# datagridView filter and sort vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, datagridview

I have the following problem.
I've a datagridView which has as datasource a list of(objects).
I need to filter the list with a text inserted in a textbox. For this, I use the following code.

```
datagridView.datasource = list.findAll(Function (x) x like textbox.text).toList
```

On the other hand, I need to sort the datagridView when the events clickHeaderColumn is raised.
For this, I use the following code

```
Private Sub DataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick 
If DataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = column.Name Then
 Dim currentSortOrder = DataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection
If currentSortOrder = SortOrder.None OrElse currentSortOrder = SortOrder.Descending Then currentSortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending
datagridView.datasource = list.orderby(Function (x) x.columnName).toList
 Else 
currentSortOrder = SortOrder.Descending
datagridView.datasource = list.orderByDescending(Function (x) x.columnName).toList
 End If DataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = currentSortOrder  
 End If End Sub
```

This last code works perfectly until I apply the filter code. Then I can not order.
The filter code works with a timer like a search bar.

Comment: You need to remember what the sort is and apply it using `OrderBy` when you filter.

Comment: The problems is when I first filter and then I want to sort by some specific column. I'LL still try what you say